# How to do grouping of sets in Sql Server and Filter records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that looks as under

```
SALES_ORDER_ID  DATEDIFFERENCE  FLAG
1               -40             1
1               -20             1
2                40             0
2               -10             1
3                12             0
4               -70             1
5                60             0
5                23             0
```

**//ddl**

```
Declare @t table (sales_order_id int,DateDifference int, Flag int)
Insert Into @t 
                Select 1,-40,1 Union All Select 1,-20,1 Union All
                Select 2,40,0 Union All Select 2,-10,1 Union All
                Select 3,12,0 Union All Select 4,-70,1 Union All
                Select 5,60,0 Union All Select 5,23,0
Select *
From @t
```

The output should be

```
sales_order_id  DateDifference  Flag
3                      12          0
5                      60          0
5                      23          0
```

i.e. the group (Sales_Order_Id) where *all the items* are having the Flag as 0.

I mean Sales_Order_Id = 2 will not appear since at least one item is not zero (2,-10,1)

Please do ask me if the information is not sufficient.

How to do this query?

Edit

I found my answer.. though still looking for a more elegant one

```
 ;with cte as(
    Select 
        sales_order_id = Case when x.sales_order_id is null then y.sales_order_id else x.sales_order_id end 
        ,x.CountFor0
        ,y.CountFor1
    From 
            (Select sales_order_id,CountFor0 = count(*)
            from @t 
            where Flag = 0
            group by sales_order_id )x
    Full Join 

            (Select sales_order_id,CountFor1 =count(*)
            from @t 
            where Flag = 1
            group by sales_order_id )y
    On x.sales_order_id = y.sales_order_id)

    Select *
    From cte
    where CountFor1 is null
```

Thanks to all

Since I don't have much reputation , so cannot post my answer in answer section

Comment: Not sure why i have been downvoted.. Is there any thing wrong in the question i asked?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congratulations for answering your own question!!

Comment: Good Work! +1 for answering your own question!

Comment: +1 for the clear problem statement

Comment: **'Group (Sales_Order_Id) where all the items are having the Flag as 0',** This is what you want ryt.. if so, then what you have tried is complicated.. i gave a simple solution for this.. try that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT sales_order_id,DateDifference,Flag FROM @t WHERE sales_order_id NOT IN 
 (SELECT sales_order_id FROM @t WHERE Flag=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

I think that will help:

```
Select * from @t WHERE FLAG=0;
```

Comment: I asked about the set..that won't give the desire output

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I understand what you are trying to do. You can use `NOT EXISTS`, as others have suggested ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8804d/4)):

```
SELECT *
FROM @t T1
WHERE Flag = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @t T2 
    WHERE T1.sales_order_id = T2.sales_order_id
    AND T2.Flag <> 0)
```

You can also use `NOT IN`, as others have also suggested ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8804d/5)):

```
SELECT *
FROM @t T1
WHERE Flag = 0
AND sales_order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT sales_order_id 
    FROM @t T2 
    WHERE T2.Flag <> 0)
```

And you can even use a `JOIN` and check the joined table has no row (id is NULL) ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8804d/6)):

```
SELECT *
FROM @t T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t T2 ON T1.sales_order_id = T2.sales_order_id AND T2.Flag <> 0
WHERE T1.Flag = 0
AND T2.sales_order_id IS NULL
```

---

Original answer:

You need a [`WHERE` clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to filter the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t
WHERE Flag = 0
```

Check out the sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8804d/2)

I am assuming you also want the `(2,40,0)` row in the results, though.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that this is a great place to use windows functions:

```
select sales_order_id, DateDifference, flag
from (select t.*, SUM(flag) over (partition by sales_order_id) as sumflag
      from @t t
     ) t
where sumflag = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from @T as T1
where not exists(select *
                 from @T as T2
                 where T1.sales_order_id = T2.sales_order_id and
                       T2.Flag = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * From @t 
where Flag=0 and sales_order_id not in 
(select sales_order_id from @t  where Flag !=0)
```